# Keras flask API not giving me output

Tags: api, flask, keras, python-3.6

I am very new to flask. I developed a document classification model using CNN model in Keras in Python3. Below is the code i am using for `app.py` file in windows machine.

I got the code example from [here](https://github.com/harkous/production_ml/blob/master/app.py) and improvised it to suit my needs

```
import os
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
from flask import Flask
import numpy as np
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, text_to_word_sequence
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences


#star Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

path = 'C:/Users/user/Model/'
json_file = open(path+'/model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
keras_model_loaded = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
keras_model_loaded.load_weights(path+'/model.h5')
print('Model loaded...')

def preprocess_text(text,num_max = 1000,max_review_length = 100):
    tok = Tokenizer(num_words=num_max)
    tok.fit_on_texts(texts)
    cnn_texts_seq = tok.texts_to_sequences(texts)
    cnn_texts_mat = sequence.pad_sequences(cnn_texts_seq,maxlen=max_review_length)
    return cnn_texts_mat

# URL that we'll use to make predictions using get and post
@app.route('/predict',methods=['GET','POST'])

def predict():
    try:
        text = request.args.get('text')
        x = preprocess_text(text)
        y = int(np.round(keras_model_loaded.predict(x)))
        #print(y)
        return jsonify({'prediction': str(y)})
    except:
        response = jsonify({'error': 'problem predicting'})
        response.status_code = 400
        return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    # Run locally
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

In my windows machine i navigate to the path in the console where i have saved `app.py` file and execute the command `py -3.6 app.py`

When i go the url `http://localhost:5000/predict` and type in browser

```
http://localhost:5000/predict?text=I've had my Fire HD 8 two weeks now and I love it. This tablet is a great value. We are Prime Members and that is where this tablet SHINES.
```

it does not give me any class as output, but instead i get this as output `{"error":"problem predicting"}`.

Any help on how to fix this?

Edit: I removed the `try` except `block` in the predict function. Below is how predict function looks like

```
def predict():
    text = request.args.get('text')
    x = preprocess_text(text)
    y = int(np.round(keras_model_loaded.predict(x)))
    return jsonify({'prediction': str(y)})
```

Now i am getting exception. error message is

```
[2018-05-28 18:33:59,008] ERROR in app: Exception on /predict [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 59, in predict
    x = preprocess_text(text)
  File "app.py", line 37, in preprocess_text
    tok.fit_on_texts(texts)
NameError: name 'texts' is not defined
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2018 18:33:59] "GET /predict?text=I%27ve%20had%20my%20Fire%20HD%208%20two%20weeks%20now%20and%20I%20love%20it.%20This%20tablet%20is%20a%20great%20value.%20We%20are%20Prime%20Members%20and%20that%20is%20where%20this%20tablet%20SHINES. HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Edit2: I have edited code to

```
def preprocess_text(texts,num_max = 1000,max_review_length = 100):
    tok = Tokenizer(num_words=num_max)
    tok.fit_on_texts(texts)
    cnn_texts_seq = tok.texts_to_sequences(texts)
    cnn_texts_mat = pad_sequences(cnn_texts_seq,maxlen=max_review_length)
    return cnn_texts_mat

# URL that we'll use to make predictions using get and post
@app.route('/predict',methods=['GET','POST'])

def predict():
    text = request.args.get('text')
    x = preprocess_text(text)
    y = keras_model_loaded.predict(x)
    return jsonify({'prediction': str(y)})
```

and now the error message is

`packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3402, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("output/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2018 19:39:11] "GET /predict?text=I%27ve%20had%20my%20Fire%20HD%208%20two%20weeks%20now%20and%20I%20love%20it.%20This%20tablet%20is%20a%20great%20value.%20We%20are%20Prime%20Members%20and%20that%20is%20where%20this%20tablet%20SHINES. HTTP/1.1" 500 -`

I am unable to understand and debug this error. Not sure what this means. Can anyone help me understand this error and suggest a solution for this?

Also, i am unable to post the entire error message in stackoverflow as most of the chunk in my question appears to be code.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it is what I guessed. There is a problem when using cross-threads with Flask and Tensorflow. Here is a fix for it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# ...
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
def predict():
  text = request.args.get('text')
  x = preprocess_text(text)
  with graph.as_default():
    y = int(np.round(keras_model_loaded.predict(x)))
  return jsonify({'prediction': str(y)})
```

by wrapping the prediction to forcefully use the default graph.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work :( what else could be wrong? I triple checked my code and everything.